# Javascript - Calling object's method within object giving error: 'Object has no method getStartPoint'

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

How to call **getStartPoint()** in startPoint, in the below code?

```
var obj = (function () {
    return {
        defaults: {
            prop: {
                getStartPoint: function () {
                    // more login ...
                },
                getEndPoint:   function () {
                    // more login ...
                },
                startPoint: this.getStartPoint(),
                endPoint:   this.getEndPoint(),
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

I am getting error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object ... has no method 'getStartPoint'

in all these: getStartPoint(), this.getStartPoint(), obj.defaults.prop.getStartPoint()

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
var obj = (function () {
    function getStartPoint() {
        console.log("getStartPoint");
    }
    function getEndPoint() {
        console.log("getEndPoint");
    }
    return {
        defaults: {
            prop: {
                getStartPoint: getStartPoint,
                getEndPoint: getEndPoint,
                startPoint: getStartPoint(),
                endPoint: getEndPoint()
            }
        }
    };
})();
```

Another:

```
function Obj() {
    if (!(this instanceof Obj)) return new Obj();
    this.defaults = {
        prop: {
            startPoint: this.defaults.prop.getStartPoint(),
            endPoint: this.defaults.prop.getEndPoint()
        }
    };
}

Obj.prototype = {
    defaults: {
        prop: {
            getStartPoint: function () {
                console.log("getStartPoint");
            },
            getEndPoint: function () {
                console.log("getEndPoint");
            }
        }
    }
};

var obj = new Obj();
```